# Invalid object name on create table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code, but I can not get it work. I get the error msg: 
Invalid object name 'ad_hoc_raportointi.dbo.tuote_testi'. I am trying to create a new table to DB1  and the query data from DB2 and insert it to DB1 table. the db already exists, but the table should be created there.

I am trying to write to my test db (ad_hoc_raportointi) and create a table called dbo.tuote_testi but I keep bumping in the same error , but I don´t know why. If you could please help me and tell me what am I doing wrong.

```
USE [LemonDB0922]
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Hae_tuote_kuva_tiedot3
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
if not exists (select * from [ad_hoc_raportointi].[dbo.tuote_testi])
    create table [ad_hoc_raportointi].[dbo.tuote_testi] (
    tuoteID int ,
    tuoteKoodi int ,
    tuotekuvaus varchar(200) ,
    tuotetarkempikuvaus varchar(200) ,
    tuotevarastossa SMALLINT ,
    tuotehinta decimal(16,2) ,
    tuoteverot SMALLINT ,
    tuote_myyntitili int ,
    tuote_guid varchar(200) ,
    tuote_viim_paivitys datetime ,
    tuote_kuva_tuote_relaatio int ,
    tuote_kuva_hexa varbinary(MAX) ,
    tuote_kuva_koko_nimi varchar(50) ,
    tuote_kuva_paate varchar(10) ,              
    PRIMARY KEY (tuoteID)

)

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO [ad_hoc_raportointi].[dbo.tuote_testi](tuoteID,tuoteKoodi,tuotekuvaus, tuotetarkempikuvaus, tuotevarastossa, tuotehinta, tuoteverot, tuote_myyntitili, tuote_guid, tuote_viim_paivitys , tuote_kuva_tuote_relaatio , tuote_kuva_hexa , tuote_kuva_koko_nimi, tuote_kuva_paate)
    SELECT  dbo.products.product_id, dbo.products.product_code, dbo.products.product_description, dbo.products.product_description2, dbo.products.product_nonstock_bit, dbo.products.product_price, dbo.products.product_include_tax_bit, dbo.products.sales_account, dbo.products.product_guid, dbo.products.product_last_upd_date, dbo.program_images.program_image_dataid , dbo.program_images.program_image_image ,   dbo.program_images.program_image_description, dbo.program_images.program_image_prefix 
    FROM [LemonDB0922].[dbo.products]   
    LEFT JOIN [LemonDB0922].dbo.program_images
    ON dbo.program_images.program_image_dataid = dbo.products.product_id

END
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `[ad_hoc_raportointi].[dbo].[tuote_testi]` not `[ad_hoc_raportointi].[dbo.tuote_testi]` for all of your queries.
You call a table as `[ad_hoc_raportointi].[dbo.tuote_testi]` but I guess in your DB there is `ad_hoc_raportointi.dbo.[tuote_testi]`. Using `[]` you give a name `[dbo.tuote_testi]` to table it's not the same as `[dbo].[tuote_testi]`.

Comment: Thanks. You were a big help!